# Относительные даты в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую плагин wp relative date, чтобы выводить такие как Сегодня, Вчера.
Но есть проблемы с датами попозже, там стоять скобки

> 11.12.2015 () 22:10

его код

```
   $output = $before.$the_date.' ('.sprintf(_n('', '', $day_diff, 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n($day_diff)).')'.$after;
            }
```

которые я как тока не пытался убрать, но не получилось. Так же как сделать так, чтобы если эта дата была позавчера 13.12.2015 не показывало время, время использую простой the_time

```
<div class="meta">
            <?php relative_post_the_date(); ?> <?php the_time( $d ); ?> 
        </div>
```

Сама функция выглядит так

```
### Alternative To WordPress the_date().
function relative_post_the_date($d = '', $before = '', $after = '', $display_ago_only = false, $display = true) {
    global $post;
    if (empty($d)) {
        $the_date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_date);
    } else {
        $the_date = mysql2date($d, $post->post_date);
    }
    if(gmdate('Y', current_time('timestamp')) != mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date, false)) {
        $output = $before.$the_date.$after;
    } else {
        $day_diff = (gmdate('z', current_time('timestamp')) - mysql2date('z', $post->post_date, false));
        if($day_diff < 0) { $day_diff = 32; }
        if($day_diff == 0) {
            $output = $before.__('Сегодня', 'wp-relativedate').$after;
        } elseif($day_diff == 1) {
            $output = $before. __('Вчера', 'wp-relativedate').$after;
        } elseif ($day_diff < 7) {
            if($display_ago_only) {
                $output = $before.sprintf(_n('', '', $day_diff, 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n($day_diff)).$after;
            } else {
                $output = $before.$the_date.' ('.sprintf(_n('', '', $day_diff, 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n($day_diff)).')'.$after;
            }
        } elseif ($day_diff < 31) {
            if($display_ago_only) {
                $output = $before.sprintf(_n('', '', ceil($day_diff/7), 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n(ceil($day_diff/7))).$after;
            } else {
                $output = $before.$the_date.' ('.sprintf(_n('', '', ceil($day_diff/7), 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n(ceil($day_diff/7))).')'.$after;
            }
        } else {
            $output = $before.$the_date.$after;
        }
    }
    if($display) {
        echo $output;
    } else {
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните где стоят скобки?

Comment: @tutankhamun блин забыл совсем, вот указал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скобки выводятся в двух местах

```
    } elseif ($day_diff < 7) {
        ...
        } else {
/* ---> тут   */ $output = $before.$the_date.' ('.sprintf(_n('', '', $day_diff, 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n($day_diff)).')'.$after;
        }
    } elseif ($day_diff < 31) {
        ...
        } else {
/* ---> и тут */ $output = $before.$the_date.' ('.sprintf(_n('', '', ceil($day_diff/7), 'wp-relativedate'), number_format_i18n(ceil($day_diff/7))).')'.$after;
        }
    } else {
```

Уберите из обеих строк и они не будут отображаться (ну и если у вас есть кеширование страниц, нужно очистить кеш, иначе будете бороться с ветряными мельницами очень долго)

С временем получается не очень хорошо. Нужна поверка, которую можно, конечно вставить в кусок `<?php the_time( $d );`, но получится довольно громоздко. Можно написать свою функцию в файле `functions.php` текущей темы и вызывать ее вместо `the_time()`.

Например так:

```
function special_post_time($d = '') {
    global $post;
    $day_diff = (gmdate('z', current_time('timestamp'))
        - mysql2date('z', $post->post_date, false));
    if ($day_diff < 2) {
        the_time($d);
    }
}
```

Comment: удалил, ничего не поменялось, ничего кеширующего не ставил на wp.

Comment: А все, появились. Остался лишь вопрос, как сделать так чтобы если дата позавчерашняя или старше, то время не показывать?

Comment: @reddyk Отключите на странице JavaScript и посмотрите еще раз